# Showing ACF text field shortcode value using ACF repeater field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode, acfpro

I’m trying to show the text field value using ACF shortcode with ACF repeater field. But instead of displaying the shortcode value it’s showing the shortcode itself. Can anyone please let me know how can I output the text value of shortcode using ACF repeater field. Please see the attachment for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a shortcode from php, you'll need to use the `do_shortcode()` function. See here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/